# Bootstrap5 - Conditional col & row depending on breakpoints

Tags: layout, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I want to align an image, a title and a text block responsively using the bootstrap layout classes.

For the sm/xs breakpoint the title is supposed to be aligned next to the image in the top left corner, the text in full width (12col) underneath.

For the md breakpoint the text should align beneath the title but next to the image.

Here's a example image of the desired layout.

[image: example layout]

I assigned a col for each element in one row.
if I assign more than 12 column widths and push down the third column (text) with an offset, it will be aligned in a second row, while I want it to share the height of the image.

My brain hurts, thanks a lot for help and hints in any directions!

This is one of the many html sceletons I tried

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image col-sm-6  col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="title col-sm-6  col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="text  col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted

Comment: Added, however I tried a lot of different solutions, none worked. Seems to me I need a conditional container wrapping either img & title in xs/sm or wrapping title & text in md and bigger.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 5? If so, there are no col-xs-* classes

Comment: Pardon, my bad. It's a custom breakpoint for < sm

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

I suggest you to make two text boxes (i.e., `text_1` and `text_2`). Use Bootstrap classes to show/hide them depending on the viewport width. To do so, apply `d-md-block d-none` to the `text_1` and `d-md-none d-block` to the `text_2`.

See the snippet below.

```css
#image {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 200px;
}

#title {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 30px;
}

#text_1,
#text_2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#text_2 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row d-flex justify-content-between mb-3'>
      <div class='col-6' id='image'>Image</div>
      <div class='col-6 pe-0'>
        <div class='col-6 w-100 mb-3' id='title'>Title</div>
        <div class='col-6 w-100 h-75 d-md-block d-none' id='text_1'>Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-12 d-md-none d-block' id='text_2'>Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```